# Is it safe to create a session from an auth token?

Tags: authentication, csrf, django

My server is using Django Rest Framework. My mobile app logs in using token authentication. However, I also have a webview in the mobile app where I need to log in. I can't inject the auth token on every request in the webview, so I use the auth token for authenticating this endpoint and then create a session from it. This is the code:

```
class CreateSessionView(APIView):
    authentication_classes = [TokenAuthentication]
    permission_classes = (permissions.AllowAny,)
    throttle_classes = [ScopedRateThrottle]
    throttle_scope = 'auth_token_verify'
    renderer_classes = [TemplateHTMLRenderer]

    def get(self, request, format=None):
        return Response({}, template_name='pages/create-session.html')
        # this template has a <form> that includes a {% csrf_token %} and authtoken


    @method_decorator(csrf_protect)
    def post(self, request, format=None):
        try:
            user = Token.objects.get(key=request.POST['authtoken']).user
            login(request, user, backend='django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend')
        except:
            raise AuthenticationFailed() 
        return redirect(reverse('home'))
```

My question is: Is there a vulnerability here? If so, how can I secure it?

Comment: When dealing with sessions, you must always use CSRF protection.

Comment: @bhorkarg I did some research and you're right.

Comment: Need to explain your question more (I deleted my answer for now). How would the sequence of calls go? Is it that you would first GET (the csrf token and the authtoken) from your app and then load the data into the WebView? And then the user would POST a form in the WebView to login?

Comment: @bhorkarg I have an endpoint that has a form with an embedded CSRF token. The web view loads that endpoint (GET), and the some JS on the page autosubmits (POST) with the CSRF and auth tokens.

Comment: How do you get the auth token to the form in the first place for the JS to autosubmit? Wouldn't this be some sort of a chicken-or-egg problem? - to get auth token you need to be logged in but to log in you need the auth token. If I understand correctly, you'd be giving out the auth token in the GET request without any authentication.

Comment: @bhorkarg I have an endpoint that you can get an auth token from with your login info. The mobile app uses this and saves the auth token for its other uses. So the user has already logged in and we have the token. For the web view in the mobile app, it's a different context and I can't modify the header of every request to inject the auth token, only the initial page, so I initialize to this session creation page with the injected auth token header, and persist the login in the web view.

Comment: I understand it now. I think as far as you use HTTPS, the approach doesn't ring any safety bells when it comes to passing the auth token to create a session as you are injecting it rather than passing it as a url parameter (which would have been visible in browser history if you weren't using a webview). However, I will let an expert to provide a canonical answer. It seems that there is no standard approach. [Here is a similar question](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/60667/secure-way-of-opening-web-page-from-ios-without-need-of-logging-in?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

See the answer here, it may help: [Session Authentication vs Token Authentication](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/81756/session-authentication-vs-token-authentication)

From what I understand from the answer, there is nothing wrong with using a token to authenticate, and then generating a session from the aforementioned token.